# Help creating this query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I'd like to integrate the following query:

```
SELECT
    parent.id
  , COUNT(child.id) AS child_count
FROM
             messages parent
  INNER JOIN messages child
    ON child.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE parent.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY parent.id;
```

into this query:

```
SELECT m.id,m.seen, m.uid, m.hash, m.date_created,m.subject,
m.textplain,m.texthtml, CONCAT_WS('@', a.localpart, a.domain ) 
AS address 
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN message_address_fields maf ON maf.message_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON a.id = maf.address_id 
WHERE maf.field_id =4 AND m.user_id =1
```

Here's a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bef27/1

Here's my schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addresses` (
   `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
   `name` text NOT NULL,
   `localpart` text NOT NULL,
   `domain` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fields` (
   `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_folder_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `texthtml` text NOT NULL,
  `textplain` text NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `seen` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `flagged` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_address_fields` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `field_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks for the help!

**QUESTION: This query limits the data to only `messages` that contain an address with field id of 4. How would I make it optional to have a correlated address with a field id of 4 or not**

Comment: Please show us the query you're using. I promise we're not here to steal your code or your business.

Comment: Also helpful is creating a basic example http://sqlfiddle.com  example since you're using mysql.

Comment: Updated my question. Going to create a fiddle now

Comment: Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ddb4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT m.id,m.seen, m.uid, m.hash, m.date_created,m.subject,
       m.textplain,m.texthtml, CONCAT_WS('@', a.localpart, a.domain) address,
       (
         SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM messages parent JOIN messages child
             ON child.parent_id = parent.id
          WHERE parent.id = m.id
       ) child_count
  FROM messages m LEFT JOIN message_address_fields maf 
    ON maf.message_id = m.id LEFT JOIN addresses a 
    ON a.id = maf.address_id
 WHERE maf.field_id = 4 
   AND m.user_id = 1 
 LIMIT 30
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | SEEN | UID | ... | CHILD_COUNT |
------------------- ... ---------------
|  1 |    0 |   2 | ... |           2 |
|  2 |    0 |   3 | ... |           0 |
|  3 |    0 |   4 | ... |           0 |
|  4 |    0 |   5 | ... |           0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bef27/15)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.id,m.seen, m.uid, m.hash, m.date_created,m.subject,
m.textplain,m.texthtml, CONCAT_WS('@', a.localpart, a.domain ) 
AS address,COUNT(child.id) AS child_count 
FROM messages m 
INNER JOIN messages child ON child.parent_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN message_address_fields maf ON maf.message_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON a.id = maf.address_id 
WHERE maf.field_id =4 AND m.user_id =1 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: this does not work because if there are no children than it doesnt show the row